# Event Grid doesn't trigger using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I have to create a Logic App using the Event Grid, so whenever a new file is created/uploaded in our General Purpose V2 Storage Account it should post a message in slack. This is how it currently looks like.

[image]

However, once one file is created/uploaded nothing shows up in slack. There aren't any runs in the "Runs history" and trying to press the button to "Run Trigger" causes the this error.

[image]

I also tried to create the Grid Topic and use the Event Grid Subscription for it, yet I got the same error.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Im facing issue with local debug /run using VS code. 
any idea how to use vscode for local run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your trigger from your picture. There aren't  any runs in the Runs history, this means your trigger is not triggered.

Note:**When a resource event occurs** this trigger could only be triggered by the blob file modification including creating blob and renaming. If your action is the container modification, it won't trigger it. And you could check the `See trigger history`.

And about your trigger error `Failed to start a logic app run`, this is because you run the trigger in the portal, the expression `@triggerBody()` will be null it won't trigger the flow.

Then I test with different storage account and different logic app ,all of them could be triggered.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it wasn't necessary to try those. Funny enough is that I kept trying to solve this problem for one week before asking for help here. Yet when I woke up today to try again, it was working just fine. I have no idea how it was fixed. Maybe it was an issue on Microsoft side?

Comment: @Spectrum , if this could help you , you could mark it as the answer.Thanks! If this issue come again or you think it's azure bug you could go to feedback to the official [site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Im facing issue with local debug /run using VS code. any idea how to use vscode for local run ? –

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when EventGrid was not registered as a resource provider on my subscription (which basically means EventGrid is not enabled).

To see if it has been registered, go to your **Subscription** and look under **Settings** for **Resource providers** and click it.

Look for Microsoft.EventGrid and make sure it is registered. If it is not (as in my case) then select it and click register. When you are done, it should look like the screenshot below.

*Note: It may take a little while for EventGrid to be up and running after you do this.*

[image: Register EventGrid]

Comment: Im facing issue with local debug /run using VS code. any idea how to use vscode for local run ? –

Answer (score -1):

Register EventGrid as a Resource Provider in your Subscription.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).